# How do I prevent a leading zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this, but it can start with 0 on this code, how can I delete it automatically when 0 is written at the beginning.

```js
    $(document).on('input','.phone',function(e){
        var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="phone" type="text"  />
```

Comment: Do you still need  3,3,4 grouping?, as just deleting the 0 would make it 2,3,4 grouping.

Comment: @Keith replace(/^0|\D/g, '') Thank you this code was very helpful.